# How to add a keyname to every element in an array in Nifi (Json)

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

I am quite new to Nifi and I already run into an issue:

I have a list of items in an array:

```
{
    "locations": [
        1,
        2,
        3
    ]
}
```

I want to transform this to:

```
{
    "locations": [
        {
            "locationid": 1
        },
        {
            "locationid": 2
        },
        {
            "locationid": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

Any ideas?

(After this I also want to add another element from a nifi attribute, but I think I will be able to manage that myself.)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind:

```
  [
      {
        "operation": "shift",
        "spec": {
          "locations": {
            "*": {
              "@": "[#2].locationID"
                                                         }
                                          }
                            }
              },
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta", 
    "spec": {
         
            "*": {
              "ReportTimestamp": "${ReportTimestamp:toDate('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'):toNumber()}"
            }
                  
      }
    
  }
]
```

Comment: And for add another value use the another object with `"operetaion": "default"`.

Comment: This did the trick for me (I wanted to add Unix time from a date in string in a Nifi Attribute):
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta", 
    "spec": {
         
            "*": {
              "ReportTimestamp": "${ReportTimestamp:toDate('yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss'):toNumber()}"
            }                  
      }    
  }